# How can I create a column with the number of months since a user joined (first date for each id), and group all ids that joined on that month in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here's some more detail, since it's a bit hard to clearly ask this question in a sentence:

Basically, I have a table with some of the following fields:

```
| ID       | date                 | start_date            | amount_paid | last_amount_paid | field      |
| -------- | ---------------------| ----------------------| ----------- | ---------------- | ---------- |
| ID_00001 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00  | 2019-11-06 20:23:36   | 0           |  0               | cosmetics  |
| ID_00002 | 2020-08-02 00:00:00  | 2018-10-06 10:34:21   | 10          |  0               | finance    |
| ...      | ...                  | ...                   | ...         |  ...             | ...        |
| ID_99999 | 2021-11-06 00:00:00  | 2020-08-01 11:54:47   | 15          |  10              | software   |
```

What I want is to add a "months" column that counts the number of months between the start date and date for each ID, for example:

```
| ID       | date                 | start_date            | ...  | months     |
| -------- | ---------------------| ----------------------| ---- | ---------- |
| ID_00001 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00  | 2019-11-06 20:23:36   | ...  |  9         |
| ID_00002 | 2020-08-02 00:00:00  | 2018-10-06 10:34:21   | ...  |  22        |
| ...      | ...                  | ...                   | ...  |  ...       |
| ID_99999 | 2021-11-06 00:00:00  | 2020-08-01 11:54:47   | ...  |  15        |
```

I then want to group all IDs that have started (first start date) at the same time together (i.e. I want to group users by number of months).

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my mind around doing this using SnowflakeSQL.

**The goal here is basically to track revenue by cohorts based on when they joined.** Please let me know if my approach is wrong and how you would go about implementing that.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using computed/generated column and [DATEDIFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(id TEXT,
                          date DATE,
                          start_date DATE,
                          months INT AS  (DATEDIFF(MONTH, start_date, date))
                         );
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO t(id, date, start_date)
SELECT  'ID_00001',  '2020-08-01 00:00:00', '2019-11-06 20:23:36'
UNION SELECT  'ID_00002', '2020-08-02 00:00:00', '2018-10-06 10:34:21';

SELECT * FROM t;
```

Output:

[image]

---

Alernatively wrapping table with a view:

```
CREATE VIEW t_vw
AS
SELECT t.id, t.start_date, t.date, DATEDIFF(MONTH, start_date, date) AS months
FROM t;
```